# How to separate #defined arguments in C

Tags: c, syntax

I'm working on an embedded project and I have all the ports and pins defined like this:

```
#define SENSOR_1 gpioPortA,15
```

Is there a way to extract just the integer without creating a new #define?

So far I used a typedef and assigned the pin value from the #define like so:

```
typedef struct
{
    GPIO_Port_TypeDef   port; 
    uint8_t       pin; 
}sensor_t;

sensor_t sensor1 = {SENSOR_1};
/* Now sensor1.pin is the pin value */
```

but I want to pass the pin to a switch case and I can only use constant values for that and I'd rather avoid using an `if` statement.

Is there a way to pass the pin to a switch case without a new #define?

Comment: This is a very unusual (and dangerous) way of using defines. Absolutely no way of type checking, very hard for the reader to understand how the struct will be initialized.

Comment: More normal way would be to have 2 defines, `SENSOR_1_PORT` and `SENSOR_1_PIN` for example.

Comment: Can you include the actual `switch`/`case` statement in your question, perhaps with some other defined sensors? It seems like you are doing something wrong IMHO.

Comment: @Groo Dangerous is to think a C pre-processor definition could be not dangerous.

Comment: Maybe something along the lines of `#define GET_SECOND(a,b) b` `#define GET_PIN(sensor) GET_SECOND(sensor)` but I haven't tried it.

Comment: @ceving: well `#define PI (3.14)` is much less dangerous than `#define sum(a,b) a+b`. :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can define a macro to extract the value from your definition.

```
#define GET_SECOND(x, y) y
#define PIN_VALUE(x) GET_SECOND(x)

switch (pin) {
case PIN_VALUE(SENSOR_1):
    /* ... */
    break;
}
```

`PIN_VALUE` must allow `SENSOR_1` to be expanded via helper macro so that the second part can be extracted.

Answer (score 4):

Short answer is no.

You could however use `sensor1.pin` when needed but not in `case` of `switch` statement as switch does not support variables there. In this case use `if-else` statement.

Or do it like this:

```
#define SENSOR_1_PIN   10
#define SENSOR_1       my_port,SENSOR_1_PIN
```

and then in switch you use `SENSOR_1_PIN` in `case` part.

```
switch (condition) {
    case SENSOR_1_PIN:
        //Do stuff
        break;
    //....
}
```

Just to remind again as it was posted in first comment on your question. Doing that is very dangerous.

Most proper way would be to do it like this:

```
#define SENSOR_1_PORT   GPIOB
#define SENSOR_1_PIN    15

//If structure order changes here, you may lead to wrong data interpretation
sensor_t sensor1 = {SENSOR_1_PORT, SENSOR_1_PIN};
```

If you are C99 compliant, you may do it even more safer like this:

```
//If structure order changes here, your data are still properly assigned to fields
sensor_t sensor1 = {.port = SENSOR_1_PORT, .pin = SENSOR_1_PIN};
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper solution at this point is to re-design the definitions into something that makes more sense, or alternatively create new constants.

As a last resort, if you are stuck with these macros, you can parse them in the following way:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdint.h>

typedef int GPIO_Port_TypeDef; // whatever type this happens to be

typedef struct
{
    GPIO_Port_TypeDef   port; 
    uint8_t       pin; 
}sensor_t;

#define GET_FIELD(field,...) (sensor_t){__VA_ARGS__}.field

#define SENSOR_1 gpioPortA,15

int main (void)
{
  int gpioPortA = 1;

  printf("%d %d", GET_FIELD(port, SENSOR_1), GET_FIELD(pin, SENSOR_1));
}
```

The type-generic version would be:

```
#define GET_FIELD(type, field, ...) (type){__VA_ARGS__}.field
...
printf("%d %d", GET_FIELD(sensor_t, port, SENSOR_1), GET_FIELD(sensor_t, pin, SENSOR_1));
```

This scales variably no matter how many fields there are. This is however not recommended practice. Macros in general, and variadic macros in particular, should be avoided.

---

As for how to use run-time variables in `case` - you can't. Use an `if-else if` statement instead.

Comment: You are still not able to do `case` in your code. Case can only accept constants.

Comment: @tilz0R This answers how to extract the fields. You can't use `case` on run-time variables. I'll update.

Comment: Ok, that is true and I agree. But this is only for this example. Maybe what he also wanted is some generic way to extract define. Unfortunatelly, I don't believe it exists.

Answer (score 0):

What about inserting a define inside a define ? Instead of directly adding 15, you could make a define holding 15 and insert it elsewhere.

E.g:

```
#define SENSORVAL 15
#define SENSOR_1 gpioPortA,SENSORVAL
typedef struct
{
    GPIO_Port_TypeDef   port; 
    uint8_t       pin; 
}sensor_t;

sensor_t sensor1 = {SENSOR_1};
/* Now sensor1.pin is the pin value */
```